# Simple Inequality proof when h is small enough

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I'm stuck trying to proof that my matrix is strictly diagonal dominant.
At one point I arrive at this inequality that must be true in order to be SDD:
$$|\frac{-2}{h²}-q(x_i)|<|\frac{1}{h²}+\frac{p(x_i)}{2h}|+|\frac{1}{h²}-\frac{p(x_i)}{2h}|$$
where $q(x)>0 \forall x $ $$\\$$I'm thinking that if $h$ is small enough I could get the result I'm looking for, but I don't know how to prove it. If h is small enough then $\frac{1}{h²}>\frac{p(x)}{2h}$ you could remove the absolute value signs in both inequalities and I get $q(x_i)<0$.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be relevant to include *how* you arrive at this inequality. The issue may have been before.

Comment: I've just discretize a lineal equation like $u''(x)=q(x)u(x)+p(x)u'(x)+r(x)$ where $x \in \left[ a, b \right]$ using the usual derivative aproximation $u'(x_i)=\frac{u(x_i+h)-u(x_i-h)}{2h}$ and write it like a matrix